# Configuring Startup Applications in Redhat 5

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, gnome-terminal, workspace

I have a RedHat 5 OS and when it starts up, several gnome terminals starts up at specific workspaces and position. I wonder how I can configure my startup applications.

Answer (score 0):

More info makes it easier:
does it happen on everyones login? or only a specific user?
do you have compiz running?

If you have compiz running then it could be in the "places" plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`System` | `Preferences` | `Startup Applications`. Or maybe `Sessions`. I don't really run EL as a desktop.